# how to display a webpage in a different way through 2 different links?

Tags: javascript, html

So, my question is that I have to display a webpage in 2 different ways when I click on 2 different links. If I click link 1, the webpage I would like to display, will hide some content and display to the user. If I click link 2, the webpage will display in a default method. I know how to hide the content using JS and CSS. But how to make the other page know what to display? Should I send any unique variable to let it know, on what to display?

Comment: You can send some value in query string to differentiate the link1 and link2 like
http://example.com?lk=1 and http://example.com?lk=2

Comment: Or just create two pages that both include the same content, except one page doesn't include the bit you want to "hide".

Comment: Why do you "have to"? Because without a very good explanation of that: no, you don't.

Comment: You need to access http headers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript like what Naveen Chandra Tiwari answered.